# How do I change the MAC address of a iMac G3?

Tags: internet, mac-os-classic, imac-g3

I want to connect an iMac G3 running Mac OS 8.6 to my Ethernet network. The easiest way for me to do this is to change the iMac's MAC address.

Is it possible to change the MAC address and, if so, how should I do it?

Comment: Why do you think that's the easiest way? Millions of machines with fixed MAC addresses connect to IP networks every day.

Comment: 1) That's almost assuredly not the easiest way. 2) You should be able to do this via OpenFirmware.  To display the machine's MAC address you can use `dev enet` followed by `.properties` but I'm not totally sure how you'd go about setting it. Here's [an OpenFirmware quick reference](http://www.firmworks.com/QuickRef.html) and a [sample device tree](https://johannes.sipsolutions.net/PowerBook/openfirmware-device-tree/) to get you started (look for `mac-address`).

Comment: @paxdiablo My network has a MAC address whitelist that I don't control. The iMac's MAC address isn't on the list.

Comment: Why not NAT it?

Comment: @andypea - then one might say it isn’t your network and whoever controls the list might be unhappy.

Comment: "My network has a MAC address whitelist that I don't control" means that you almost certainly should *not* be trying to do this. Talk to the people that *do* control your whitelist.

Comment: Is it your ISP that forces you to have a MAC address whitelist?

Comment: @user253751 OP may not be on a traditional sort of privately-contracted ISP. For example, when I was a college student living on-campus, we were only allowed to submit 1 MAC address for the network at a time. In order to change that MAC address, we had to contact the ISP, and wait several hours if not a whole day. I learned about spoofing real quick back then.

Comment: @BrianReading Then it should probably not be referred to as "my network"

Comment: @user253751 Semantics. A network that you connect to in which others on here would not use could certainly be referred to as "my" network. Perhaps they don't own the network, but they use it. Much like how people use the term "my school". It's not their school, it's the school they attended.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Thanks for the tips. I made a bit of progress using the `ewrite-bit` word, but ended up using Relocated in the end. OpenFirmware and its Forth interface are really fascinating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a piece of abandonware called "Relocated" that was written by Robert Sixkiller & Adriaan Mol in the early 2000s. It will allow you to change (spoof) your MAC address in MacOS 8 and 9. You can find a copy [here](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/1210-relocated).